# Enqueue Style Only On Certain Pages Not Working

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-style, css

I am trying to enqueue Bootstrap's CSS only on two pages.

Here's the code I have in my `functions.php` file:

```
function bootstrap_css() {
    if (is_page('who-we-are-2') ||  is_front_page()) {
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrapstyle', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrap_css');
```

From other StackExchange questions and Googling, that code should work. It works for the home page, but not on the "who-we-are-2" page. What's odd is `is_page('who-we-are-2')` doesn't work by itself. I have also tried `is_page(32365)` and `is_page('32365')`, 32365 being the page ID to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That should work. Is 'who-we-are-2' published? Have you tried deactivating all your plugins so your theme is the only thing enqueueing files?

Comment: The page was set to private published. Tried it normal published and no luck. I need a couple plugins for the page to work, but I disabled everything else. No dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:
It looks like it has something to do with the URL. For some reason I can view the page at /who-we-are-2 and it looks normal, minus the scripts/styles I am trying to enqueue. But the page should really be at /about/who-we-are-2 as About is the parent page. If I go to /about/who-we-are-2 it works perfectly. /about/who-we-are-2 is what is in the nav and the URL that users will see so we're all good. And obviously my enqueue wouldn't work on /who-we-are-2 since my `if` statement didn't call for that page. So ultimately, problem solved. But I'd love to know why I can view the page at /who-we-are-2 if anyone knows!